# MS Sync Framework Deploy with a Pre Populated Database?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I'd like to deploy an application with a pre-populated Sql CE Database.

Steps:
1) At Deploy: Create sql ce databse using LocalDataCache object in VS 2010 and have it prepopulated.  Zip up this db and put it on the server.
2) Client: Downloads the app
3) Client App: Downloads the zipped up database and unzips it.
4) Client App: Does a sync against a WCF Service against the original db and only pulls down the incremental changes.

I've got the above working up until step 4.
At step 4 the wcf services are returning all the data in the database (i.e. it's treating my local database as if it's empty. I imagine the reason for this is due to anchors being out of sync.

What I'd like to do is at deploy time to reset the anchors so that the server only returns the changes that happened between the deploy and the client download & sync.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to isolate the logic for syncing databases in a separate project, make a small console app that creates the db, prepopulates it by syncing directly against the master database, zips it and puts it on the server automatically. You can then trigger this console app manually or as part of your build process.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do what is called "snapshot initialization". Have a look at this article for more information about snapshot initialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294193.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

at step #1, am assuming you didnt choose snapshot? snapshots dont store anchors.

if you want to play around with the anchors, you can actually read/write to them in the SqlCeClientSyncProvider's GetTableReceivedAnchor() and SetTableReceivedAnchor()